# Intellij GUI Designer .. resizing components with mouse

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

I cannot find a way to resize components placed on a JPanel by using the mouse.. the components just snap back to preset values in the properties panel. I would have imagined that if i resize by mouse those values would follow??

I have noted on other posts that there are two Horizontal and Vertical Size Policy properties that can be set to 'Can shrink/grow' .. but i cannot see those options in my GUI Designer:

[image: No Horizontal Size Policy]

I must be missing something very simple ... but .. well IDK!!

Answer (score 0):

The size of components in a Swing user interface is determined by the layout manager and depends on the size of the window (or JPanel in your case) in which the components are contained. You cannot resize components directly.

With some layout managers, you can specify constraints on the size of the components (such as minimum and maximum size), and with others the size of the components depends only on the size of the container and the distribution of this size between components (shown as "Weight X" and "Weight Y" on your screenshot).

Comment: Okay ... that is what i have been lead to understand ... but i am left wondering why components, when selected, present handles inviting the user to resize by the mouse?? I am not sure i understand if it is called a WYSIWYG editor why you cannot see what you will get before previewing?? I have been searching for some instructional/tutorial (video) that can point out the basic navigation and best practices for using the Layout Managers ... but alas .. by chance can you help here yole?? :)

Comment: The handles allow you to select how many grid squares a component occupies. The UI designer, to the best of my knowledge, isn't called a WYSIWIG editor anywhere in either the product or its documentation.

Comment: Aaah .. then that is where i am going wrong! I shall stop treating it as if it is!! Thanks.:)